# Implement personal access token in aspnet zero application using IdentitySever 4

Tags: access-token, identityserver4, aspnetboilerplate

I am implementing **personal access token** in my aspnet zero application. I came across some challenges while implementing this. I am working with multi-tenant application where each tenant will get an access token to access the system.

It will basically store the **client Id** and **client secret** for each tenant into the database and based on this, personal access token is generated. For this, I have created the identity server Client entity and its related entities , I referred this link : https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/tree/dev/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework

I am able to generate the client keys and also stored these keys into the database.

After this, we need to configure identity server, I followed above link to configure identity server in startup file. But, things are not seem to be working for me. Is there any sample implementation to get clients from database and configure identity server for personal access token?

Thanks.

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Identity-Server

Comment: Thanks @AlperEbicoglu for sharing the link. However, we want the client information from the database as we have stored the client keys into database.